# HTML image is not loading. Its showing the alt. But not the image

Tags: html

My HTML code is not displaying the image. I have tried a lot of times.

```
<img style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="../static/aircondition.jpg" alt="Air Condition">
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRbtb.png)

Comment: Please check your path  which you give to src

Comment: can you include your file structure?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if your provided `src` directory is correct or not